# Regex match for multiple characters

Tags: regex

I want to write a regex pattern to match a string starting with "Z" and not containing the next 2 characters as "IU" followed by any other characters.

I am using this pattern but it is not working  **Z[^(IU)]+.*$**

1. ZISADR - should match
2. ZIUSADR - should not match
3. ZDDDDR - should match

Comment: why ZISADR is not a valid match?

Comment: Edited the question, ZISADR is a valid match

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
^Z(?:I[^U]|[^I]).*$
```

[**Click for Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/4fmfTP/5)

**Explanation:**

- `^` - asserts the start of the line
- `Z` - matches `Z`
- `I[^U]` - matches `I` followed by any character that is not a `U`
- `|` - OR
- `[^I]` - matches any character that is not a `I`
- `.*` - matches 0+ occurrences of any character that is not a new line
- `$` - asserts the end of the line

Comment: This doesnt work. I need 2 characters "I" and "U". My string ZISADR will not match.

Comment: This works. Thanks so much. but this looks complex. isnt there a simpler way?

Comment: A negative lookahead would have looked "simpler" but as you said it is not supported. Will update the answer if I come up with a better solution

Comment: This won't match strings `ZAUDSD` where as it should match as Z is not followed by `IU`

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi You are correct. I did not consider that case. I am deleting the answer

Comment: @Gurman: You don't have to delete your answer. Your answer just misses one more alternation to handle all cases. Check my answer.

Comment: @Gurman: Another variation [`^Z(?:[^I]U|.[^U]).*$`](https://regex101.com/r/4fmfTP/6)

Answer (score 5):

When you want to negate certain characters in a string, you can use character class but when you want to negate more than one character in a particular sequence, you need to use negative look ahead and write your regex like this,

```
^Z(?!IU).*$
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OMBYyf/1)**

Also note, your first word `ZISADR` will match as `Z` is not followed by `IU`

Your regex, `Z[^(IU)]+.*$` will match the starting with `Z` and `[^(IU)]+` character class will match any character other than `(` `I` `U` and `)` one or more times further followed by `.*` means it will match any characters zero or more times which is not the behavior you wanted.

**Edit: To provide a solution without look ahead**

A non-lookahead based solution would be to use this regex,

```
^Z(?:I[^U]|[^I]U|[^I][^U]).*$
```

This regex has three main alternations which incorporate all cases needed to cover.

- `I[^U]` - Ensures if second character is `I` then third shouldn't be `U`
- `[^I]U` - Ensures if third character is `U` then second shouldn't be `I`
- `[^I][^U]` - Ensures that both second and third characters shouldn't be `I` and `U` altogether.

**[Demo non-look ahead based solution](https://regex101.com/r/OMBYyf/3)**

Comment: I tried this and i know this will work. But i am using Kusto query language and i have been told that this does not support negative lookahead. https://kusto.azurewebsites.net/docs/query/re2.html

Comment: @UllasPrabhu: Updated my answer with a non-lookahead based regex.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi How about simply [`^Z(?:I[^U]|[^I]).*$`](https://regex101.com/r/4fmfTP/5) ?

Comment: @Gurman: Yes that works too and even better than mine. Kudos.